# Jquery select all unchecked radio with text == FOO

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rh0dium/kRy2N/3/ where I am trying to create a "Mark all unanswered.." as FOO.  But I am having a trouble with the last two parts.  The first is the selector to find all labels which contain a radio in which haven't been answered.  I have tried various combinations of:

```
var inputs = $('input:radio:not(:checked):contains("' + value + '")');
```

But none of them seem to grab it.  Furthermore once I get them how do I ensure that it

1. Isn't already answered.
2. Ensure that for a given label you only get one answer.
3. Add it back to the list so if the user changes his mind we can reset it.  That is the purpose of the `answers`.

Am I looking at this wrong? or could some jquery guru help me out.

**Updated**

http://jsfiddle.net/rh0dium/kRy2N/4/

Thanks

Comment: Use `$('input:radio:not(:checked)[value*="' + value + '"]');` instead.

Comment: Ricardo You have the right answer for the problem.  Please post this as an answer.

Comment: Right, added the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will get all `radio` that's not checked and value contains `value`

```
$('input:radio:not(:checked)[value*="' + value + '"]');
```

Comment: For everyone else - Ricardo had the answer almost immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var answers = [];
    $("#multi_choice_change").change(function() {
        var value = $("select#multi_choice_change option:selected").val();
        console.log("Changed to " + value);
        //Remove checked from unmatched radio buttons
        $('input:radio[value!="'+value+'"]').prop('checked',false);
        //add checked to matched radio buttons 
        $('input:radio[value="'+value+'"]').prop('checked','checked');
         })
});
```

Comment: This actually shifts what I was looking to do.  I wanted it very narrowly scoped as this will change all answers. Thanks!

Comment: Is this solved your issues? if so please approve this answer :) else clarify your requirement.